Accessing Azure File Share when port 445 is blocked, while maintaining access to on prem DNS for name resolution
Currently port 445 is blocked for endpoints attempting to access a file share in Azure. I have two options, use Azure File Sync, or use a VPN / ExpressRoute.
By using a VPN, will I have the same issue as below, where I lose DNS resolution with my on-prem infrastructure?
We have a hybrid setup, on prem DC with DNS resolution, A records are created for our Azure VM's (which are not domain joined, they are on a workgroup).
To access Azure environment, we have a P2S VPN configuration using certificates for authentication. Since there is no DNS resolution on the Azure side, I can no longer access my on-prem network mapped folders or remote desktop connections without specifying an IP address.
I suppose this is my first issue. Do I need to configure DNS on Azure?
Key points:

Need access to Azure File Share network mapped drive when ISP blocks port 445
Currently no DNS is configured in Azure with my hybrid environment
Current P2S Azure VPN blocks access to on prem DNS network, which occurs when I need access to Azure.


Do I need to configure DNS on Azure? name resolution is nearly always required. Or use a hosts file. Why would a host not have name resolution?

I agree with you Greg, it's just the way the environment has been configured and inherited. The way it is currently setup works to some extent but I suppose I was looking for an answer on my best approach for setting up which azure VPN to use in order to gain access to my Azure File Share and maintain the ability to access my on prem file shares and servers.
If it is possible to solve our problems with just the host files then that will suffice, it's the solution with no added costs from Azure.

There's something fundamentally wrong with the design. Establishing a connection to a resource should not disrupt other services.

The first main problem I believe is that the Azure VM's are not domain joined, they are in a workgroup. Because of this, I don't think host files would work anyway right?
With the way it is set up, we have DNS A records on the on prem DC for each on prem server and the Azure servers, so when the Azure P2S VPN is connected, in order to access a network file share, the FQDN is required.
Outside of this, the Azure VM's have no connectivity whatsoever to the on-prem infrastructure.
